# How overlap UV of repeating faces

Tags: uv

I have cylindrical mesh. I need to unwrap it in a way that stacks its segments on each other. So that I can save space and make a nice repeating pattern.

[image]

How can I do that? This question obviously is a repeat, but I couldn't find an even proper term for what I want.

**UPD.** I'd like to keep parts proportional(I want to do the same with upper portion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the faces and press **u** for unwrap and press **reset**, so all will be squares (Enable stretch in right properties in uv editor for better seeing). Now select the faces you want to repeat then enable **uv and mesh sync** in uv editor. Now select faces in 3d view then scale down in uv editor and move aside, similarly, repeat manually (press two adjacent faces and press **shift+cltr+(numpad +)** to grow selection based on previous selection). Finally press A to select all and **cltr+a** to average all islands. using box select **b** select group of islands move them where you needed. I hope this helps.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thx for the response it works nicely. But how do I restore proportions now? I want to do the same with the upper portion too. Should I unwrap one face and then align others on it?

Comment: If you want proportions, then rather than resetting uv, with normal uvs select each face and pres G and hold Cltr while moving to snap to  nearest vertices ( not increment type) and release . Repeat for  four faces with box select and move aside with only pressing G. Repeat eight times. you have to do it manually.